# PHP code not executing when javascript comes between

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Here is the situation... Two results are created in the php page.. The results are echoed as `json_encode` . The results are showing perfectly. But when i insert a javascript code within two php code blocks, then one result is shown while the other is not.. I really have no idea why this is happening.. My code

```
$action = isset($_GET['action']);
if($action == "get_requests"){

include("../connect.php");


    $sql_song_req = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `song_requests`";
    $sql_select_song = "SELECT * FROM `song_requests` ORDER BY id ASC";

    $sql_count = $rad->prepare($sql_song_req);
    $sql_count->execute();

    $count = $sql_count->fetchColumn();



    $select_song_prep = $rad->prepare($sql_select_song);
    $select_song_prep->execute();

    while($row = $select_song_prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $song = $row['songname'];
        $dedicatedto = $row['dedicatedto'];
        ?>
        <script>
            function delete_req(id){
        alert("hello");
            }
        </script>
        <?php

        $data .= '  <tr cellpadding="5" cellspacing="6" align="center" width="60%">
                <td>'.$id.'</td>
                <td>'.$name.'</td>
                <td>'.$song.'</td>
                <td>'.$dedicatedto.'</td>
                <td><a href="javascript:;" onclick="delete_req('.$id.');" style="background:black; color:white; padding:8px;">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>';

    }


    $display = '    <table "cellspacing="4" align="center">
            <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Song</th>
            <th>Dedicated to</th>
            <th>Delete</th>

            '.$data.'           

            </tr>
            </table>';


        $response = array();
            $response['data_from_db'] = $display;
        $response['count'] = $count;
        echo json_encode($response);

}
```

Here the `response['count']` is showing on my php page but not `$response['data_from_db']`.
And when I delete the javascript code then both of them are showing.. Help needed.

I should mention that  am using NGINX and php5-fpm

Answer (score 0):

You have a brace mismatch.

Add a brace `}` after `$dedicatedto = $row['dedicatedto'];` Your `while` loop wasn't properly closed.

```
$action = isset($_GET['action']);
if($action == "get_requests"){

include("../connect.php");

    $sql_song_req = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `song_requests`";
    $sql_select_song = "SELECT * FROM `song_requests` ORDER BY id ASC";

    $sql_count = $rad->prepare($sql_song_req);
    $sql_count->execute();

    $count = $sql_count->fetchColumn();

    $select_song_prep = $rad->prepare($sql_select_song);
    $select_song_prep->execute();

    while($row = $select_song_prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $song = $row['songname'];
        $dedicatedto = $row['dedicatedto'];
        } // <- added. Brace for while loop
        ?>
        <script>
            function delete_req(id){
        alert("hello");
            }
        </script>
        <?php

        $data .= '  <tr cellpadding="5" cellspacing="6" align="center" width="60%">
                <td>'.$id.'</td>
                <td>'.$name.'</td>
                <td>'.$song.'</td>
                <td>'.$dedicatedto.'</td>
                <td><a href="javascript:;" onclick="delete_req('.$id.');" style="background:black; color:white; padding:8px;">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>';

    $display = '    <table "cellspacing="4" align="center">
            <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Song</th>
            <th>Dedicated to</th>
            <th>Delete</th>

            '.$data.'           

            </tr>
            </table>';


        $response = array();
            $response['data_from_db'] = $display;
        $response['count'] = $count;
        echo json_encode($response);

}
```

Comment: Does the JS function have to be in its present place? Why not just put it on top of PHP? I think that's where the problem is now. It's because the conditional statement wrapped within everything. Do you want everything execute IF the condition meets, because right now, everything inside `if($action == "get_requests"){` and right down to `echo json_encode($response);` is executed. @nick You could also echo the JS also then get rid of a `<?php` tag altogether.

Comment: ok i put it at the top.. and guess what still it's the same problem.. what is actually wrong? is it because of the json?

Comment: No, it's most likely because you're going in and out of PHP and the JS is right in the middle outside of PHP, while the conditional statement is wrapping everything, rendering it invalid and causing havoc/problems. @nick

Comment: [`See this comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612035/php-code-not-executing-when-javascript-comes-between#comment34432540_22612035) that has been given. @nick

Comment: I can't see why it could be doing this, since all what the JS is doing is calling a function `delete_req()` when clicked, which I find indeed bizarre. @nick